# extract data from JSON string

Tags: json, data

I've got to extract a license plate digit and it's associated confidence  from a JSON string that looks like:

```js
{
  "response": {
    "container": {
      "id": "0df307bc-06b2-45cf-b7ff-ce07fd04e04d",
      "timestamp": "2018-Jul-10 17:34:27.448632"
    },
    "id": "00000002-0000-0000-0000-000000000015"
  },
  "frames": {
    "frame": {
      "id": "5583",
      "timestamp": "2016-Nov-30 13:05:27",
      "lps": {
        "lp": {
          "licenseplate": "15451BBL",
          "text": "15451BBL",
          "wtext": "15451BBL",
          "confidence": "20",
          "bkcolor": "16777215",
          "color": "16777215",
          "type": "0",
          "ntip": "11",
          "cct_country_short": "",
          "cct_state_short": "",
          "tips": {
            "tip": {
              "poly": {
                "p": { "x": "1094", "y": "643" },
                "p": { "x": "1099", "y": "643" },
                "p": { "x": "1099", "y": "667" },
                "p": { "x": "1094", "y": "667" }
              },
              "bkcolor": "16777215",
              "color": "0",
              "code": "49",
              "code_ascii": "1",
              "confidence": "97"
            },
            "tip": {
              "poly": {
                "p": { "x": "1103", "y": "642" },
                "p": { "x": "1113", "y": "642" },
                "p": { "x": "1112", "y": "667" },
                "p": { "x": "1102", "y": "667" }
              },
              "bkcolor": "16777215",
              "color": "0",
              "code": "53",
              "code_ascii": "5",
              "confidence": "89"
            },
            "tip": {
              "poly": {
                "p": { "x": "1112", "y": "640" },
                "p": { "x": "1122", "y": "640" },
                "p": { "x": "1122", "y": "666" },
                "p": { "x": "1112", "y": "666" }
              },
              "bkcolor": "16777215",
              "color": "0",
              "code": "52",
              "code_ascii": "4",
              "confidence": "97"
            },
            "tip": {
              "poly": {
                "p": { "x": "1123", "y": "640" },
                "p": { "x": "1132", "y": "640" },
                "p": { "x": "1131", "y": "665" },
                "p": { "x": "1123", "y": "665" }
              },
              "bkcolor": "16777215",
              "color": "0",
              "code": "53",
              "code_ascii": "5",
              "confidence": "97"
            },
            "tip": {
              "poly": {
                "p": { "x": "1134", "y": "640" },
                "p": { "x": "1139", "y": "640" },
                "p": { "x": "1139", "y": "664" },
                "p": { "x": "1133", "y": "664" }
              },
              "bkcolor": "16777215",
              "color": "0",
              "code": "49",
              "code_ascii": "1",
              "confidence": "77"
            },
            "tip": {
              "poly": {
                "p": { "x": "1154", "y": "639" },
                "p": { "x": "1163", "y": "639" },
                "p": { "x": "1163", "y": "663" },
                "p": { "x": "1153", "y": "663" }
              },
              "bkcolor": "16777215",
              "color": "0",
              "code": "66",
              "code_ascii": "B",
              "confidence": "97"
            },
            "tip": {
              "poly": {
                "p": { "x": "1164", "y": "638" },
                "p": { "x": "1173", "y": "638" },
                "p": { "x": "1173", "y": "663" },
                "p": { "x": "1163", "y": "663" }
              },
              "bkcolor": "16777215",
              "color": "0",
              "code": "66",
              "code_ascii": "B",
              "confidence": "94"
            },
            "tip": {
              "poly": {
                "p": { "x": "1191", "y": "637" },
                "p": { "x": "1206", "y": "636" },
                "p": { "x": "1205", "y": "660" },
                "p": { "x": "1190", "y": "661" }
              },
              "bkcolor": "16777215",
              "color": "0",
              "code": "76",
              "code_ascii": "L",
              "confidence": "34"
            },
            "tip": {
              "poly": {
                "p": { "x": "1103", "y": "655" },
                "p": { "x": "1111", "y": "655" },
                "p": { "x": "1111", "y": "667" },
                "p": { "x": "1103", "y": "667" }
              },
              "bkcolor": "16777215",
              "color": "0",
              "code": "74",
              "code_ascii": "J",
              "confidence": "57"
            },
            "tip": {
              "poly": {
                "p": { "x": "1103", "y": "655" },
                "p": { "x": "1111", "y": "655" },
                "p": { "x": "1111", "y": "667" },
                "p": { "x": "1103", "y": "667" }
              },
              "bkcolor": "16777215",
              "color": "0",
              "code": "74",
              "code_ascii": "J",
              "confidence": "57"
            },
            "tip": {
              "poly": {
                "p": { "x": "1176", "y": "638" },
                "p": { "x": "1185", "y": "637" },
                "p": { "x": "1184", "y": "661" },
                "p": { "x": "1175", "y": "662" }
              },
              "bkcolor": "16777215",
              "color": "0",
              "code": "52",
              "code_ascii": "4",
              "confidence": "7"
            }
          },
          "ncharacter": "8",
          "characters": {
            "characater": {
              "poly": {
                "p": { "x": "1094", "y": "643" },
                "p": { "x": "1099", "y": "643" },
                "p": { "x": "1099", "y": "667" },
                "p": { "x": "1094", "y": "667" }
              },
              "bkcolor": "16777215",
              "color": "0",
              "code": "49",
              "code_ascii": "1",
              "confidence": "97"
            },
            "characater": {
              "poly": {
                "p": { "x": "1103", "y": "642" },
                "p": { "x": "1113", "y": "642" },
                "p": { "x": "1112", "y": "667" },
                "p": { "x": "1102", "y": "667" }
              },
              "bkcolor": "16777215",
              "color": "0",
              "code": "53",
              "code_ascii": "5",
              "confidence": "89"
            },
            "characater": {
              "poly": {
                "p": { "x": "1112", "y": "640" },
                "p": { "x": "1122", "y": "640" },
                "p": { "x": "1122", "y": "666" },
                "p": { "x": "1112", "y": "666" }
              },
              "bkcolor": "16777215",
              "color": "0",
              "code": "52",
              "code_ascii": "4",
              "confidence": "97"
            },
            "characater": {
              "poly": {
                "p": { "x": "1123", "y": "640" },
                "p": { "x": "1132", "y": "640" },
                "p": { "x": "1131", "y": "665" },
                "p": { "x": "1123", "y": "665" }
              },
              "bkcolor": "16777215",
              "color": "0",
              "code": "53",
              "code_ascii": "5",
              "confidence": "97"
            },
            "characater": {
              "poly": {
                "p": { "x": "1134", "y": "640" },
                "p": { "x": "1139", "y": "640" },
                "p": { "x": "1139", "y": "664" },
                "p": { "x": "1133", "y": "664" }
              },
              "bkcolor": "16777215",
              "color": "0",
              "code": "49",
              "code_ascii": "1",
              "confidence": "77"
            },
            "characater": {
              "poly": {
                "p": { "x": "1154", "y": "639" },
                "p": { "x": "1163", "y": "639" },
                "p": { "x": "1163", "y": "663" },
                "p": { "x": "1153", "y": "663" }
              },
              "bkcolor": "16777215",
              "color": "0",
              "code": "66",
              "code_ascii": "B",
              "confidence": "97"
            },
            "characater": {
              "poly": {
                "p": { "x": "1164", "y": "638" },
                "p": { "x": "1173", "y": "638" },
                "p": { "x": "1173", "y": "663" },
                "p": { "x": "1163", "y": "663" }
              },
              "bkcolor": "16777215",
              "color": "0",
              "code": "66",
              "code_ascii": "B",
              "confidence": "94"
            },
            "characater": {
              "poly": {
                "p": { "x": "1191", "y": "637" },
                "p": { "x": "1206", "y": "636" },
                "p": { "x": "1205", "y": "660" },
                "p": { "x": "1190", "y": "661" }
              },
              "bkcolor": "16777215",
              "color": "0",
              "code": "76",
              "code_ascii": "L",
              "confidence": "34"
            }
          },
          "det_time_us": "1104009",
          "poly": {
            "p": { "x": "1088", "y": "642" },
            "p": { "x": "1210", "y": "634" },
            "p": { "x": "1210", "y": "661" },
            "p": { "x": "1087", "y": "669" }
          }
        }
      },
      "det_time_us": "1710270"
    }
  }
}
```

I've got something like:

```
$ jq -r '.frames.frame.lps.lp|.characters.characater.code_ascii,.characters.characater.confidence' test.json
```

but it only returns one single letter & it's conf. score....

#### Question

- How can I get all letters and the associated score back?

#### Output

I expect the output to be like:

```
1 97, 5 89, 4 97,5 97, 1 77,B 97, B 94, L 34, J, 57,J 57, 4 7, 1 97, 5 89, 4 97, 5 97, 1 77, B 97, B 94, L 34
```

**NOTE:** format can be different, this is just indicating the data I wanted to extract.

#### copy & paste

input file "test.json"

```
{"response":{"container":{"id":"41d6efcb-24d6-490d-8880-762255519b5f","timestamp":"2018-Jul-11 19:51:06.461665"},"id":"00000002-0000-0000-0000-000000000015"},"frames":{"frame":{"id":"5583","timestamp":"2016-Nov-30 13:05:27","lps":{"lp":{"licenseplate":"15451BBL","text":"15451BBL","wtext":"15451BBL","confidence":"20","bkcolor":"16777215","color":"16777215","type":"0","ntip":"11","cct_country_short":"","cct_state_short":"","tips":{"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1094","y":"643"},"p":{"x":"1099","y":"643"},"p":{"x":"1099","y":"667"},"p":{"x":"1094","y":"667"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"49","code_ascii":"1","confidence":"97"},"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1103","y":"642"},"p":{"x":"1113","y":"642"},"p":{"x":"1112","y":"667"},"p":{"x":"1102","y":"667"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"53","code_ascii":"5","confidence":"89"},"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1112","y":"640"},"p":{"x":"1122","y":"640"},"p":{"x":"1122","y":"666"},"p":{"x":"1112","y":"666"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"52","code_ascii":"4","confidence":"97"},"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1123","y":"640"},"p":{"x":"1132","y":"640"},"p":{"x":"1131","y":"665"},"p":{"x":"1123","y":"665"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"53","code_ascii":"5","confidence":"97"},"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1134","y":"640"},"p":{"x":"1139","y":"640"},"p":{"x":"1139","y":"664"},"p":{"x":"1133","y":"664"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"49","code_ascii":"1","confidence":"77"},"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1154","y":"639"},"p":{"x":"1163","y":"639"},"p":{"x":"1163","y":"663"},"p":{"x":"1153","y":"663"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"66","code_ascii":"B","confidence":"97"},"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1164","y":"638"},"p":{"x":"1173","y":"638"},"p":{"x":"1173","y":"663"},"p":{"x":"1163","y":"663"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"66","code_ascii":"B","confidence":"94"},"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1191","y":"637"},"p":{"x":"1206","y":"636"},"p":{"x":"1205","y":"660"},"p":{"x":"1190","y":"661"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"76","code_ascii":"L","confidence":"34"},"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1103","y":"655"},"p":{"x":"1111","y":"655"},"p":{"x":"1111","y":"667"},"p":{"x":"1103","y":"667"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"74","code_ascii":"J","confidence":"57"},"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1103","y":"655"},"p":{"x":"1111","y":"655"},"p":{"x":"1111","y":"667"},"p":{"x":"1103","y":"667"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"74","code_ascii":"J","confidence":"57"},"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1176","y":"638"},"p":{"x":"1185","y":"637"},"p":{"x":"1184","y":"661"},"p":{"x":"1175","y":"662"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"52","code_ascii":"4","confidence":"7"}},"ncharacter":"8","characters":{"characater":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1094","y":"643"},"p":{"x":"1099","y":"643"},"p":{"x":"1099","y":"667"},"p":{"x":"1094","y":"667"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"49","code_ascii":"1","confidence":"97"},"characater":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1103","y":"642"},"p":{"x":"1113","y":"642"},"p":{"x":"1112","y":"667"},"p":{"x":"1102","y":"667"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"53","code_ascii":"5","confidence":"89"},"characater":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1112","y":"640"},"p":{"x":"1122","y":"640"},"p":{"x":"1122","y":"666"},"p":{"x":"1112","y":"666"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"52","code_ascii":"4","confidence":"97"},"characater":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1123","y":"640"},"p":{"x":"1132","y":"640"},"p":{"x":"1131","y":"665"},"p":{"x":"1123","y":"665"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"53","code_ascii":"5","confidence":"97"},"characater":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1134","y":"640"},"p":{"x":"1139","y":"640"},"p":{"x":"1139","y":"664"},"p":{"x":"1133","y":"664"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"49","code_ascii":"1","confidence":"77"},"characater":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1154","y":"639"},"p":{"x":"1163","y":"639"},"p":{"x":"1163","y":"663"},"p":{"x":"1153","y":"663"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"66","code_ascii":"B","confidence":"97"},"characater":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1164","y":"638"},"p":{"x":"1173","y":"638"},"p":{"x":"1173","y":"663"},"p":{"x":"1163","y":"663"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"66","code_ascii":"B","confidence":"94"},"characater":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1191","y":"637"},"p":{"x":"1206","y":"636"},"p":{"x":"1205","y":"660"},"p":{"x":"1190","y":"661"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"76","code_ascii":"L","confidence":"34"}},"det_time_us":"1072592","poly":{"p":{"x":"1088","y":"642"},"p":{"x":"1210","y":"634"},"p":{"x":"1210","y":"661"},"p":{"x":"1087","y":"669"}}}},"det_time_us":"1720812"}}}
```

### link

input file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18wCzjMBpw7SIeVFByAGPQiqCBjg_0te3/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This doesn't seem like valid JSON data to me - https://jsonlint.com/ shows it as invalid - SyntaxError: Duplicate key 'p' on line 32.

Comment: @slm yes, i saw this as a warning too but I can't modify the string. This is what I'm receiving from a third party module... :(

Comment: @cerr - when I started trying to parse it it's not putting the letters into an array, so it's tough to parse that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a new and improved answer.  The old answer is available after the divider at the end.

The issue with the data is that it contains an object, `.frame.frames.lps.lp.characters`, with non-unique keys (`characater`).  Each time a value is given for an already existing key, the old value is lost.

We can work around this with `jq` by using the utility's "stream" input (`--stream`):

```bash
$ jq -r -n --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(5|truncate_stream(inputs)|select(.[0][0] == "characater"))) | [.code_ascii, .confidence] | @tsv' test.json
1       97
5       89
4       97
5       97
1       77
B       97
B       94
L       34
```

This first truncates the input stream at depth 5 (the length of the path `.frame.frames.lps.lp.characters`), and we extract any sub-path that starts with the problematic `characater` key. This is what the inner `truncate_stream()` and the `select()` are doing. The top level of every such sub-path is then truncated, and what remains is reconstituted into a stream of objects. This is what the outer `truncate_stream()` is doing together the `fromstream()` call that wraps it.

At this point in the processing, the modified document looks like the following (given the example in the question):

```json
{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1094","y":"667"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"49","code_ascii":"1","confidence":"97"}
{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1102","y":"667"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"53","code_ascii":"5","confidence":"89"}
{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1112","y":"666"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"52","code_ascii":"4","confidence":"97"}
{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1123","y":"665"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"53","code_ascii":"5","confidence":"97"}
{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1133","y":"664"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"49","code_ascii":"1","confidence":"77"}
{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1153","y":"663"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"66","code_ascii":"B","confidence":"97"}
{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1163","y":"663"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"66","code_ascii":"B","confidence":"94"}
{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1190","y":"661"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"76","code_ascii":"L","confidence":"34"}
```

For each object from `fromstream`, the data is extracted into an array formatted for output with `@tsv`, giving us the tab-delimited output above.

---

Old answer from 2018:

Since your `characters` array is not a proper JSON array (it's a hash where each key has the same name), only the last value of it will be available.

We can fix that by preprocessing the data to create unique keys for each object that is now called `characater`:

```
awk '/"characater"/ { sub("\"characater\"", "\"char" ++n "\"", $0) } 1' file.json
```

This would replace each `characater` with `char1`, `char2` etc.

We can now access all values in that with e.g.

```
jq -r '.frames.frame.lps.lp|.characters[]|[.code_ascii,.confidence]|@tsv'
```

The complete pipeline:

```
awk '/"characater"/ { sub("\"characater\"", "\"char" ++n "\"", $0) } 1' file.json |
jq -r '.frames.frame.lps.lp|.characters[]|[.code_ascii,.confidence]|@tsv'
```

Result (given the data in the question):

```
1       97
5       89
4       97
5       97
1       77
B       97
B       94
L       34
```

If you control the generation of the JSON document, you should consider turning the `characters` object into a proper array.

Comment: This only prints two lines: `1     97` & `L    34` i.e. the `characater` to `charN` only worked for one replacement

Comment: @cerr Odd, I am using the data that you provided without modifications... Did you copy and past my `awk` code correctly?

Comment: Try: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18wCzjMBpw7SIeVFByAGPQiqCBjg_0te3/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @cerr Ah! It's all on one line.  In that case, change `sub()` to `gsub()`. No, sorry scrap that. `n` would not increment. Hold on, I need to doodle.

Comment: @kuslananda after changing `sub()` to `gsub()`, all the occurences get replaced but they now all have the same letter because - as you indicated, `n` doesn't increment... did you find something?

Comment: @cerr Yes, you can, with GNU `sed` put a newline after each `},` with `sed 's/},/},\n/g'` and _then_ pass it through the `awk` and `jq`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Much appreciated, but I need some further help, I've started a new thread, please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/455145/two-consecutive-operations-after-pipe if you're interested in assisting me further! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Given your input isn't valid JSON you'll likely have to go with a `sed`, `awk`, `grep` type of solution. To that end the following can deal with input where it's been 'minified' into a single string:

```
$ grep -oP '"code_ascii":"\w+","confidence":"\w+"' <FILE> | grep -oP '(?<=:)"\w+"' | paste - -
```

### Example

```
$ grep -oP '"code_ascii":"\w+","confidence":"\w+"' b.json | grep -oP '(?<=:)"\w+"' | paste - -
"1", "97"
"5", "89"
"4", "97"
"5", "97"
"1", "77"
"B", "97"
"B", "94"
"L", "34"
"J", "57"
"J", "57"
"4", "7"
"1", "97"
"5", "89"
"4", "97"
"5", "97"
"1", "77"
"B", "97"
"B", "94"
"L", "34"
```

#### Alternatives

**NOTE:** These work with multi-line input data.

*sed+paste*

```
$ sed -n '/code_ascii/,/confidence/p' a.json | sed 's/.*: [^"]*//' | paste - -
```

*sed,awk,paste*

```
$ sed -n '/code_ascii/,/confidence/p' a.json | awk -F': ' '{print $2}' | paste -d" " - -
```

*sed,grep,paste*

```
$ sed -n '/code_ascii/,/confidence/p' a.json | grep -oP '(?<=: ).*$' | paste - -
```

*grep+paste*

```
$ grep -oP '"code_ascii":"\w+","confidence":"\w+"' b.json | grep -oP '(?<=:)"\w+"' | paste - -
```

Comment: Get it here: http://txt.do/dzp91

Comment: @cerr - cool, I'll make another alt

Comment: @cerr - try the grep+paste one

Answer (score 1):

grep + sed + tr :

```
grep -e code_ascii -e confidence <file> |  sed 's/.*: "\(.*\)"/\1/;' | tr "\n" ' '
```

Return :

```
20, 1, 97 5, 89 4, 97 5, 97 1, 77 B, 97 B, 94 L, 34 J, 57 J, 57 4, 7 1, 97 5, 89 4, 97 5, 97 1, 77 B, 97 B, 94 L, 34
```

This command return only the pairs code_ascii + confidence :

```
 grep -e code_ascii -e confidence <file> | sed -n 's/.*code_ascii": "\(.*\)"/\1/;T;h;n;s/.*"confidence": "\(.*\)"/\1/;T;H;g;p' | tr "\n" " "
```

Return :

```
 1, 97 5, 89 4, 97 5, 97 1, 77 B, 97 B, 94 L, 34 J, 57 J, 57 4, 7 1, 97 5, 89 4, 97 5, 97 1, 77 B, 97 B, 94 L, 34
```

Now, see above the Kusalananda's post. With just sed + tr :

```
sed -i 's/},/},\n/g' <tempfile>
sed -n 's/characater//;T;:z;n;s/.*code_ascii": "\(.*\)"/\1/;Tz;:zz;h;n;s/.*"confidence": "\(.*\)"/\1/;Tzz;H;s/$//;Tz;g;p' <tempfile> | tr "\n" " "
```

Return :

```
1, 97 5, 89 4, 97 5, 97 1, 77 B, 97 B, 94 L, 34
```

Comment: Hi alux, no, for me this prints the whole JSON string. (PS: I had my filename inserted at the right spot - it's not working for me)

Comment: bizare your file code, on my debian (904), just `sed -n '/code_ascii/,/confidence/p'  tmpfile` block my consol. crtl-c oblige. Good luck

Comment: `sed -n '/code_ascii/,/confidence/p' tmpfile` will print the whole line

Comment: As written above `grep -e code_ascii -e confidence tempfile |  sed 's/.*: "\(.*\)"/\1/;' | tr "\n" ' ` works but not a simple `sed -n '/code_ascii/,/confidence/p' tmpfile` ???

Comment: He doesn't want the first 20 you're showing in your output.

Comment: Yep ! After the preprocessing command : `sed -i 's/},/},\n/g' tempfile` (@Kusalananda thanks), sed work correctely.