# Two consecutive OPs after pipe or two jq OPs in one run?

Tags: text-formatting, json, data

I have to extract data from a slightly mis-formatted JSON string, hence I first pass it through `sed` & `awk`.
What I have is a command like:

```
`sed 's/},/},\n/g' test.json |awk '/"characater"/ { gsub("\"characater\"", "\"char" ++n "\"", $0) } 1'| jq -r '.frames.frame.lps.lp|.characters[]|[.code_ascii,.confidence]|@tsv'`
```

to extract data from a JSON string that can be seen here:

```
{"response":{"container":{"id":"41d6efcb-24d6-490d-8880-762255519b5f","timestamp":"2018-Jul-11 19:51:06.461665"},"id":"00000002-0000-0000-0000-000000000015"},"frames":{"frame":{"id":"5583","timestamp":"2016-Nov-30 13:05:27","lps":{"lp":{"licenseplate":"15451BBL","text":"15451BBL","wtext":"15451BBL","confidence":"20","bkcolor":"16777215","color":"16777215","type":"0","ntip":"11","cct_country_short":"","cct_state_short":"","tips":{"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1094","y":"643"},"p":{"x":"1099","y":"643"},"p":{"x":"1099","y":"667"},"p":{"x":"1094","y":"667"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"49","code_ascii":"1","confidence":"97"},"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1103","y":"642"},"p":{"x":"1113","y":"642"},"p":{"x":"1112","y":"667"},"p":{"x":"1102","y":"667"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"53","code_ascii":"5","confidence":"89"},"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1112","y":"640"},"p":{"x":"1122","y":"640"},"p":{"x":"1122","y":"666"},"p":{"x":"1112","y":"666"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"52","code_ascii":"4","confidence":"97"},"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1123","y":"640"},"p":{"x":"1132","y":"640"},"p":{"x":"1131","y":"665"},"p":{"x":"1123","y":"665"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"53","code_ascii":"5","confidence":"97"},"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1134","y":"640"},"p":{"x":"1139","y":"640"},"p":{"x":"1139","y":"664"},"p":{"x":"1133","y":"664"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"49","code_ascii":"1","confidence":"77"},"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1154","y":"639"},"p":{"x":"1163","y":"639"},"p":{"x":"1163","y":"663"},"p":{"x":"1153","y":"663"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"66","code_ascii":"B","confidence":"97"},"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1164","y":"638"},"p":{"x":"1173","y":"638"},"p":{"x":"1173","y":"663"},"p":{"x":"1163","y":"663"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"66","code_ascii":"B","confidence":"94"},"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1191","y":"637"},"p":{"x":"1206","y":"636"},"p":{"x":"1205","y":"660"},"p":{"x":"1190","y":"661"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"76","code_ascii":"L","confidence":"34"},"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1103","y":"655"},"p":{"x":"1111","y":"655"},"p":{"x":"1111","y":"667"},"p":{"x":"1103","y":"667"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"74","code_ascii":"J","confidence":"57"},"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1103","y":"655"},"p":{"x":"1111","y":"655"},"p":{"x":"1111","y":"667"},"p":{"x":"1103","y":"667"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"74","code_ascii":"J","confidence":"57"},"tip":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1176","y":"638"},"p":{"x":"1185","y":"637"},"p":{"x":"1184","y":"661"},"p":{"x":"1175","y":"662"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"52","code_ascii":"4","confidence":"7"}},"ncharacter":"8","characters":{"characater":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1094","y":"643"},"p":{"x":"1099","y":"643"},"p":{"x":"1099","y":"667"},"p":{"x":"1094","y":"667"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"49","code_ascii":"1","confidence":"97"},"characater":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1103","y":"642"},"p":{"x":"1113","y":"642"},"p":{"x":"1112","y":"667"},"p":{"x":"1102","y":"667"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"53","code_ascii":"5","confidence":"89"},"characater":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1112","y":"640"},"p":{"x":"1122","y":"640"},"p":{"x":"1122","y":"666"},"p":{"x":"1112","y":"666"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"52","code_ascii":"4","confidence":"97"},"characater":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1123","y":"640"},"p":{"x":"1132","y":"640"},"p":{"x":"1131","y":"665"},"p":{"x":"1123","y":"665"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"53","code_ascii":"5","confidence":"97"},"characater":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1134","y":"640"},"p":{"x":"1139","y":"640"},"p":{"x":"1139","y":"664"},"p":{"x":"1133","y":"664"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"49","code_ascii":"1","confidence":"77"},"characater":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1154","y":"639"},"p":{"x":"1163","y":"639"},"p":{"x":"1163","y":"663"},"p":{"x":"1153","y":"663"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"66","code_ascii":"B","confidence":"97"},"characater":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1164","y":"638"},"p":{"x":"1173","y":"638"},"p":{"x":"1173","y":"663"},"p":{"x":"1163","y":"663"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"66","code_ascii":"B","confidence":"94"},"characater":{"poly":{"p":{"x":"1191","y":"637"},"p":{"x":"1206","y":"636"},"p":{"x":"1205","y":"660"},"p":{"x":"1190","y":"661"}},"bkcolor":"16777215","color":"0","code":"76","code_ascii":"L","confidence":"34"}},"det_time_us":"1072592","poly":{"p":{"x":"1088","y":"642"},"p":{"x":"1210","y":"634"},"p":{"x":"1210","y":"661"},"p":{"x":"1087","y":"669"}}}},"det_time_us":"1720812"}}}
```

or on this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18wCzjMBpw7SIeVFByAGPQiqCBjg_0te3/view?usp=sharing 
Now, that works fine but what I need is, to extract the `.frames.frame.lps.lp.ncharacter` from the JSON, too. I know I could simply do something like `cat test.json | jq -r '.frames.frame.lps.lp.ncharacter';` in front of the above but that won't work as I need these commands to parse a huge file of JSON strings that are formatted as seen on the link and I need the `.ncharacter` parameter to show up in line with the extracted chars what means I would like to have an output like:

```
...
X       99
Y       99 previous data formatted in the same way
8
1       97
5       89
4       97
5       97
1       77
B       97
B       94
L       34
6          following data formatted in the same way
Z       99
...
```

Where the 8 on top is the `.ncharacter` parameter.
I have tried:

```
sed 's/},/},\n/g' test.json |awk '/"characater"/ { gsub("\"characater\"", "\"char" ++n "\"", $0) } 1'| jq -r '[.frames.frame.lps.lp.ncharacter],.frames.frame.lps.lp|.characters[]|[.code_ascii,.confidence]|@tsv'
```

but that gives me `jq: error (at <stdin>:102): Cannot index array with string "characters"` and I'm not sure why that is...

Answer (score 2):

Check this:

**First variant**

```
perl -pe 's/"characater"/"\"char" . (++$n) . "\""/ge' input.json |
jq -r '.frames.frame.lps.lp|.ncharacter,(.characters[]|[.code_ascii,.confidence]|@tsv)'
```

**Explanation**

1. `perl -pe 's/"characater"/"\"char" . (++$n) . "\""/ge' input.json`

   - `-p` - loop through each line and print, like `sed`.
   - `-e` - May be used to enter one line of program. If `-e` is given, Perl will not look for a filename in the argument list.
   - `s///ge` - `g`:  global substitution, `e`: evaluate the right part of the substitution command as an expression.
   - `"\"char" . (++$n) . "\""` - dots are used for concatenation.
2. `jq -r '.frames.frame.lps.lp|.ncharacter,(.characters[]|[.code_ascii,.confidence]|@tsv)'`

   - `.frames.frame.lps.lp|` - it can be written as the `.frames | .frame | .lps | .lp |`, so it works this way: take input, pick all `frames` fields and pipe them to the another filter - `.frame`, then take all `frame` fields and pipe them to the next filter - `.lps`, so on. See [jq Manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/), the **Pipe** section.
   - `|.ncharacter,(.characters[]|...)'` - [jq Manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/), the **Comma** section: "If two filters are separated by a comma, then the same input will be fed into both and the two filters’ output value streams will be concatenated in order: first, all of the outputs produced by the left expression, and then all of the outputs produced by the right. For instance, filter `.foo, .bar`, produces both the “foo” fields and “bar” fields as separate outputs."
   - `(.characters[]|[.code_ascii,.confidence]|@tsv)` - parenthesis are used for processing `.characters[]`'s output separately from the `.ncharacter` filter output.

**Second variant** - using `gawk` instead `perl` for `json` file fixing, the `jq` part the same as in the first variant:

```
gawk '{ORS= (RT) ? "\"char" NR "\"" : ""; print}' RS='"characater"' input.json
```

**Note** - the `perl` and `gawk` commands don't reset the `char` block's counter every frame. That is, it starts from `char1` in the beginning and incrementing it to the end.

**Input** - your sample repeated by three times.

**Output**

```
8
1   97
5   89
4   97
5   97
1   77
B   97
B   94
L   34
8
1   97
5   89
4   97
5   97
1   77
B   97
B   94
L   34
8
1   97
5   89
4   97
5   97
1   77
B   97
B   94
L   34
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a continuation of another question on the same topic, and the main issue here is that the input contains an object with non-unique keys.  This is still valid JSON, but the later keys overwrite the earlier ones, so data is "lost" when the document is parsed.

[I answered the earlier question here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/455059/116858), with the following command, which is explained in the answer:

```bash
$ jq -r -n --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(5|truncate_stream(inputs)|select(.[0][0] == "characater"))) | [.code_ascii, .confidence] | @tsv' test.json
1       97
5       89
4       97
5       97
1       77
B       97
B       94
L       34
```

The issue in *this* question is that the output needs to be prepended by the number of lines outputted on a line by itself.  There is also not just a single instance of these oddly formatted JSON documents but a whole set of them, one per line.

The following is a modification of the above command which collects the result in an array before outputting it, in order to calculate the number of elements:

```bash
$ jq -r -n --stream '[fromstream(1|truncate_stream(5|truncate_stream(inputs)|select(.[0][0] == "characater"))) | [.code_ascii, .confidence]] | length, (.[]|@tsv)' test.json
8
1       97
5       89
4       97
5       97
1       77
B       97
B       94
L       34
```

Then it's just a matter of calling this command once for each line in the original file:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

cmd=( jq -r -n --stream '[fromstream(1|truncate_stream(5|truncate_stream(inputs)|select(.[0][0] == "characater"))) | [.code_ascii, .confidence]] | length, (.[]|@tsv)' )

while IFS= read -r json; do
    printf '%s\n' "$json" | "${cmd[@]}"
done <test.json
```